# testing_sm setting of intelliJ 2017

Tags: intellij-idea

There was **testing_sm** setting which exist in previous version of intelliJ and used to make TestNG run in remote mode. It is not available now in 2017.1.4 version. 
Anyone aware of why it is removed and what is the new setting to run test by Remote TestNG runner in place of default TestNG runner.

Answer (score 0):

This was an internal setting during the migration to the new protocol. As there were no problems reported after the migration, the setting is now removed as obsolete. The old protocol has caused compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks. I used to change this setting to make my test cases work using RemoteTestNG runner instead of TestNG runner. Let me know what is the new setting for this now in 2017.

Comment: There is no setting, request with more details and the steps to reproduce the problem is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.